# Custom SMS API Integration with Wordpress Contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-rest-api

I want to send an SMS by using external URL API such as https://bsms.ufone.com/bsms_v8_api/sendapi-0.3.jsp, I've created a plugin file and used curl to call the URL API as:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent','custom_api' );
function custom_api( $contact_form ) {
   $title = $contact_form->title();

   if($title === 'Contact form 1') {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if($submission)
    {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        $name = $posted_data['your-name'];
        $email = $posted_data['your-email'];
        $contact_number = $posted_data['your-contact-number'];
        $subject = $posted_data['your-subject'];
        $message = $posted_data['your-message'];

        $curl = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

         $resp = curl_exec($curl);
         curl_close($curl);
      }
    }
 }
```

The problem is that the form is submitted successfully but I'm not receiving any SMS.
What could be the issue and how to fix it?

I've defined the url as: $url= 'https://bsms.ufone.com/bsms_v8_api/sendapi-0.3.jsp?message=testing&lang=English&mobilenum=923159021409&groupname=&messagetype=Transactional; Moreover, I've also tried using wp_remote_get

Below is the response of the URL API which is basically XML file, I've tried to use the simpleXML_load_file too but it returns bool(false)

[image]

Comment: 1 - `$url` is not defined.  2 - What are you doing with the posted data. 3 - You should use `wp_remote_post` or `wp_remote_get` if you're posting or getting.

Comment: I've updated my question, Kindly check it again, Thanks

Comment: I also recommend using wp_remote_post as it's so much simpler a method for sending requests. CURL can be really tricky. Don't make it harder on yourself.

Comment: Download [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) and try sending info through. Once you get that to be successful, copy the code from Postman and insert it into your code and modify it from there. You don't have to sign up

Comment: Your code is still unclear.  URL is not defined in your function, therefore it won't be called.  Also, why are you calling the posted data if you're not using it?  This is still lacking details.

Comment: @CChoma I've mentioned that I've tried using wp_remote_get but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: @CarlBrubaker tried that too but I guess the issue is not in curl because I get a string response from curl which gets the page but it says web page blocked

Comment: @HowardE I couldn't mention the url at first because of the credentials in it but I've tried to post the logical part of the code

Comment: I've used wp_remote_get but I get 500 status code in output

Answer (score 0):

Please add the api url in `$url` also if there's any access token then please use it. Moreover, as you are using WordPress you can use `wp_remote_post` to post data. You can see the reference [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/).

Comment: I realize you are unable to comment, but this is not a solution and should not be submitted as an answer.